# navigation links move to the left on click in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, navigation

I cannot figure out why the navigation links move or jump to the left when I click them in IE but on chrome, safari, firefox they make a slight button press like animation.  I was given this blank theme and it was somehow incorporated into it. If someone can let me know how to fix just the IE problem or to remove it all together that would be appreciated. thanks

site is [www.newpathwaysretreat.com](http://www.newpathwaysretreat.com)

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you have this line ... remove it:

```
a:active { position: relative; top: 1px; }
```